# How do I take string values from a list of objects and add them to a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to take a list of employees with 3 parts, employee id, last name and first name and add them to a drop down list showing last name, first name.

What I have so far is that I created a class for the employees:

```
   public class Employee
{
    public int emp_Id;
    public string lastName;
    public string firstName;

    public Employee(int id, string last, string first)
    {
        this.emp_Id = id;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.firstName = first;
    }
}
```

and created a list to populate:

```
private List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
```

this list is populated from a sql query and then sorted by last name.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["EMPLOYEE_TABLE"].Rows)
        {
          employeeList.Add(new Employee(int.Parse(row["EMP_ID"].ToString()), 
          row["LAST_NAME"].ToString(), row["FIRST_NAME"].ToString()));
        }

 employeeList.Sort(delegate(Employee E1, Employee E2) { return E1.lastName.CompareTo(E2.lastName); });
```

and everything up to that point worked exactly as I wanted it to but I cannot figure out how I populate a dropdownlist with the last name and first name values contained in the list.

*code has been edited for readability*

Comment: I recommend sorting the employees in the sql query unless there's a particular reason not to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See code below:

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();

ddl.DataSource = employeeList;
ddl.DataTextField = "fullName";
ddl.DataValueField = "emp_Id";
```

I would also modify your class to include a full name field:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int emp_Id { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string fullName
    {
        get
        { 
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", this.firstName, this.LastName);
        }
    }

    public Employee(int id, string last, string first)
    {
        this.emp_Id = id;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.firstName = first;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarified edit. That's exactly what I am looking for. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Example with existing properties:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="bla" runat="server"  />

bla.DataSource = employeeList;
bla.DataTextField = "firstName";
bla.DataValueField = "emp_Id"
bla.DataBind();
```

**I recommend this:**

```
<asp:DropDownList id="bla" runat="server"  />

bla.DataSource = employeeList;
bla.DataTextField = "fullName";
bla.DataValueField = "emp_Id"
bla.DataBind();

public class Employee
{
    public int emp_Id;
    public string lastName;
    public string firstName;

    public string fullName get{ return firstName + " " + lastName;}

    public Employee(int id, string last, string first)
    {
        this.emp_Id = id;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.firstName = first;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra property to your class that will hold the 3 values, and use this as your DataTextField when binding the DropDownList:

Class Code

```
public class Employee
{
    public int emp_Id;
    public string lastName;
    public string firstName;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return this.ToString(); }
    }
    public Employee(int id, string last, string first)
    {
        this.emp_Id = id;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.firstName = first;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return lastName + " " + firstName + " " + emp_Id;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
ddl.DataSource = employees;
ddl.DataValueField = "emp_Id";
ddl.DataTextField = "Text";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a property called FullName to gets "FirstName + ' ' + LastName"? That would give you one field to deal with instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't modify `Employee`, you may also try something along those lines:

```
var data = employee.Select (x =>
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
        x.emp_Id,
        string.Format("{0}, {1}", x.lastName, x.firstName)
));

ddl.DataSource = data.ToList();
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataBind();
```

This may also be useful if you have different pages with different dropdowns for employees, sometimes with *Lastname* first, sometimes with *Firstname* first, and maybe with and without a colon in between ...